# Как эффективно работать с кешем в си с помощью posix_memalign

Tags: c, posix

Как эффективно работать с кешем с помощью связки `sysconf (_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)` и `posix_memalign`. Как это работает?

Comment: Лично я не представляю как с этим эффективно работать. Эффективное попадание в кеш можно наладить при конкретной задаче. Для этого нужно "правильно" расставить переменные, "правильно" выбрать размеры массивов. `sysconf (_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)` - даёт размер линии кеша. Боюсь что этот размер позволит определить будет ли программа отлаженая у вас на ПК работать так же эффективно на другом ПК, а по сути... боюсь что для каждого значения нужно подгонять или алгоритм или коэфициенты квантования. Опять алгоритм - нужен алгоритм. А без опоры - будут просто общие рекомендации как попасть в кеш

Comment: Правильно реализовать свою задачу вообще об этом не задумываясь, а уже после, если результаты для конкретного случая неудовлетворительные по времени, нужно запустить её под своим любимым профилировщиком и смотреть, возникает ли избыточное количество кеш-промахов и думать, что с этим делать для конкретной задачи. А задумываться о `sysconf (_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)` и `posix_memalign` нужно только тогда, когда потребуются соответствующие функции... пока вопрос звучит как «я нашёл молоток, что им можно забить?»

Comment: Практически - 1. Можно проверить значение _SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE, и если оно меньше чем то которое у вас на ПК, писать где-то предупреждение - что данная программа расчитана на более мощный ПК, и нет гарантии что программа тормозить не будет. 2. Если вы можете себе позволить несколько ПК с разным значением _SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE - можете написать несколько программ под разные значения - тогда программа будет эффективно работать на нескольких видах ЦП. Но это есть смысл делать только там, где ну очень нужно выиграть быстродействие - очень редкие случаи.

Comment: Возможно вы ищите что то такое http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/ ?

Comment: @nick_n_a, а вы много знаете процессоров с размером кэш-лайн не равным 64?

Comment: @avp, на третьем пеньке — `32`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, это да, с 486 (как было в 386 не нашел) по P-3 32 байта (кстати, выпускался до 2003 года), потом уже 64.